# How to restrict the URL modification visibilty in address bar?

Tags: java, web-applications, post, struts2, httprequest

I have my java project web application.  I am usning struts 2. Across the application , i make the action URL and submit it then response jsp is shown as
result but URL does not get changed in address bar(which is expected). But one jsp when i submit the action to create the employee , i see the create
customer action URL in address bar which i don't expect. I am using post method. I debugged the issue but found nothing special in request/response
object for this http request?

Comment: when you submit the page its going by action so action name is there in the address-bar, while when you get response you  are getting back response from same action, this is the standard behavior, i am not sure why you don't want URL change when you calling a action

Comment: @Umesh. This is a project stndard and happening across the project.Just wanna follow consistency

Comment: What is wrong in this question to attract negative vote i.e after 3 years ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the address of the action you posted to in the browser address bar is expected behavior.

What you should do is use the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern, so that the user can successfully refresh the page or navigate through historywithout any problem. This will also have the side-effect of displaying the URL of the action you redirect to after the creation, rather than the URL of the creation action itself.